# Usage of awk within shell - include printed result into the same input

Tags: shell, input, awk

I know this is a stupid question, and may not even be related to awk itself (more like shell), but let me explain what I need:
I want (yes, this code is wrong, but I hope you get an idea)

```
mv [awk 'BEGIN{for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { printf("file%d.png ", i) }}'] ../
```

to be interpreted as if I entered

```
mv file1.png file2.png file3.png ../
```

Basically, something like what the asterisk in

```
mv file*.png ../
```

does.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Short form: No, you can't do that safely with awk. What's your actual goal? Why do you want to use awk for it?

Comment: You don't need awk for this: `mv file{1..3}.png ../`

Comment: I actually want multiple images combined using imagemagick's tool "montage" in a very special order. My original post is just a simple example.

Comment: Describe your real goal in enough detail, and I can show you how to implement it in native bash, with no awk required. However, it might be best if that were a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this *unsafely* is easy:

```
mv $(awk 'BEGIN{for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { printf("file%d.png ", i) }}') ../
```

However, THIS IS DANGEROUS AND UNSAFE. The output of awk is string-split and glob-expanded; it cannot refer to filenames with spaces, and if it refers to a file named `*`, this will be replaced by the shell with a list of all files in the current directory; other glob expressions are expanded similarly. Don't do it.

---

Doing this *safely* with awk is hard without a substantial number of lines of bash wrapping it, because doing it *safely* requires generating a NUL-delimited list of files (which awk can do), reading that list out of awk into a shell array, and then expanding it into an argument list.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^^ arrays are bash features, so a script starting with #!/bin/sh will not work
#    even if /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash, #!/bin/sh will disable some
#    bash-only extensions.
awk_files=()
while IFS='' read -r -d '' file; do
  awk_files+=( "$file" )
done < <(awk 'BEGIN{for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { printf("file%d.png\0", i) }}')
mv "${awk_files[@]}" ../
```

The list needs to be NUL-delimited because NULs are the only characters which cannot legitimately exist in a literal filename; newlines, glob characters, and everything else is valid (`/` isn't valid within a filename proper, but as the path separator, it's entirely valid within a fully-qualified path) -- and the shell doesn't have tools for expanding such lists without multiple lines of code involved.

That said, you don't need awk at all for your example:

```
mv file{1..3}.png ../
```

...or, to mimic your awk script's logic in native bash:

```
files=()
for ((i=1; i<=3; i++)); do
  files+=( "file${i}.png" )
done
mv "${files[@]}" ../
```

Comment: I have figured it out. You have pointed me in the right direction (without having to use awk at all), so thanks a lot!